# Reset Windows Updates

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, updates

There is a neat guide on resetting updates here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971058/how-do-i-reset-windows-update-components

I have tried to create a script to automate this process, but now when checking for updates, no updates are found. Checking for updates completes (does **not** get stuck), but only 2 optional updates are found.

What am I missing?

```
@echo off
CHOICE /C Y /M "Press Y and Enter to reset Windows Updates or close this command prompt."
pause
@echo on
net stop bits
net stop wuauserv
net stop appidsvc
net stop cryptsvc
del "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\qmgr*.dat"
Ren %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.bak
Ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak
sc.exe sdset bits D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
sc.exe sdset wuauserv D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
cd /d %windir%\system32
@echo off
regsvr32.exe /s atl.dll
regsvr32.exe /s urlmon.dll
regsvr32.exe /s mshtml.dll
regsvr32.exe /s shdocvw.dll
regsvr32.exe /s browseui.dll
regsvr32.exe /s jscript.dll
regsvr32.exe /s vbscript.dll
regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml3.dll
regsvr32.exe /s msxml6.dll
regsvr32.exe /s actxprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe /s softpub.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wintrust.dll
regsvr32.exe /s dssenh.dll
regsvr32.exe /s rsaenh.dll
regsvr32.exe /s gpkcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe /s sccbase.dll
regsvr32.exe /s slbcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe /s cryptdlg.dll
regsvr32.exe /s oleaut32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s ole32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s shell32.dll
regsvr32.exe /s initpki.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuapi.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuaueng.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuaueng1.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wucltui.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wups.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wups2.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuweb.dll
regsvr32.exe /s qmgr.dll
regsvr32.exe /s qmgrprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wucltux.dll
regsvr32.exe /s muweb.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wuwebv.dll
@echo on
netsh winsock reset
net start bits
net start wuauserv
net start appidsvc
net start cryptsvc
@echo off
CHOICE /C Y /M "Press Y and Enter to restart your computer or close the command prompt (require manual restart)."
pause
shutdown.exe /r /t 00
```

Comment: You don't reset the installed updates with that. It just resets the Windows Update components to fix errors that might occur. In short, you have installed all updates that are available so it finds nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are missing anything. It looks like you did everything the website says to. It is possible that your computer only has 2 optional updates available and that is why it could be saying that. I would check the control panel to see if there are more available. If there isn't than you did it right. To check that you would go to (Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Windows Update) than click on Check for updates.